# Why does Anaconda deal with applications such as VsCode, Spyder, ...?

Tags: anaconda

I can see the benefits of Anaconda to manage environments and packages with the help of conda and adding a GUI, but I can't see the benefits of managing the applications such as vscode that are easily installed and run from desktop. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the **Anaconda distribution**, the **conda** package manager and the **Anaconda Navigator**. While the former are very useful, the Navigator is more of a concession to inexperienced beginners and not necessary at all.

Comment: ok, Anaconda navigator may be useful for beginners to graphically manage their envs and packages, but what is the point of launching an app such as vscode from navigator? Does it change anything compared to launching vscode separately?

Comment: The navigator allows you to first activate an environment and then launch VSCde, so that when you open an integrated terminal you are already in an active environment - even w/o a .py file open. But the VSCode Python extension can do that too in a more flexible way.